# which java 64bit download for Solaris 10 VM

Tags: java, solaris

I downloaded Solaris 5.10 VM (ova) for VMWare (win7 pro) and I am trying to update the pre-installed java6  x64 to java 7_79 x64 JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
It seems I have 64bit support (isainfo returns amd64) and I am trying to determine which is the correct java64 download. I am confused.
I tried **Solaris x64 16.38 MB   jdk-7u79-solaris-x64.tar.gz** but when I run java -version  I get 
 Error occurred during initialization of VM
 A fatal exception has occurred. program will exit.

I also tried another download 
Solaris x86 96.66 MB   jdk-7u79-solaris-i586.tar.gz 
but that as I suspected, turns out to be 32bit only.

I did not try the Sparc ones as I suspect they are for Sparc arch.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add the complete error?

Comment: The formatting messed it up
**  Error occurred during initialization of VM A fatal exception has occurred. program will exit.
**

Comment: Ah ok, I thought the message would be more extensive. Don't think I can help you. Sorry

Comment: If someone can tell me which link I file I need to download for Solaris 5.10 for JDK7 I would be grateful.

Comment: You posted the correct links in your question. Is there anything missing for you to accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [both the 32 bit and 64 bit packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/solaris/solaris-jdk.html#install-archive). The latter is not, as its size shows, a complete JDK but only an add-on including the 64 bit binaries/libraries.

Comment: This answer is correct. The 64-bit package is effectively an **overlay**. Simply install into same directory structure as the 32-bit package. That's it. From Java8 onwards this is no longer required as there's no longer any 32-bit Java for Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. First, uninstall all versions of java. Seconds, I noticed that the link you provided is out of date. Java 8 came out recently so you should use that unless you have compatibility issues.

[Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Choose: Solaris x64

Finally, if this does not work, uninstall and just try again with a different download from the page I provided.

Comment: Thanks, I am installing Talend 5.6.1 which is not compatible with Java 8. Solaris x64 was what I tried. Right now I am using 32bit JDK7 (...i586..) in test mode, which for my purpose is OK but I do need the 64bit for real install.